# Smart searching MYSQL varchar field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of games. I want to search by the game name. But I want the search to work in almost any circumstance.

For example, if I search "starcitizen" it should pull up the game "Star Citizen".

I've tried using LIKE, but that doesn't help obviously.

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE name LIKE '%starcitizen%';
```

I've tried using MATCH with a FULLTEXT index but that also does not pull up the correct game.

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('starcitizen' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

What do I have to do in order to get the best search results, including the above?

Comment: You need to look at proper search engine technology like Sphinx or Apache Solr

Comment: You say "if I search "starcitizen" it should pull up the game "Star Citizen"." but by what logic is this possible? It has a space in the name, your search term doesn't.

Comment: I need the search to be idiot proof. If someone forgot the space it should be able to recognize that star and citizen are two separate words and apply that to the search.

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming. You can't make anything idiot-proof. Idiocy of humans exceeds the limits of Universe. However, if you really, really want to waste time on those select few, gifted, idiotic specimens of our race - then you should investigate `Spinhx` (already mentioned) and data structure known as `trie`. If I were you, I wouldn't go down this painful path because the reward is nonexistent and the time spent will be forever lost and quite large at that. Good luck and godspeed!